# Should I be using FFT

Tags: fft, eeg

I am using python (scipy.fft) to live analize EEG data. The app resonds instantl based on the signls coming from EEG (Alpha Beta...)The problem is that when I run the FFT on only 100 samples or so (because I need the program to respond as soon as possible) it gives me very limeted frequency data, giving me only every second Hz value (2, 4, 6, 8, ...). Is there a better way to do this than FFT? Or a way to optimize the FFT. Thank you for any help! ps I am using a Muse headset, which gives 256 samples a second.

Comment: If you're capturing less than 1/2 a second of data, then there's not enough information _in your sample_ to get better than 2 (or 2.56, really) Hz of frequency resolution.  You may want to _edit your question_ to explain what you're trying to find out about your signal, and why you're only capturing a fraction of a second of it at a time.

Comment: @TimWescott done

Comment: What Tim stated and Engineers answer is correct. To add to that with 0.5 samples per second of real data, the achievable frequency range is 0 to 0.25 Hz (and likely 20% or so less than that if the waveform was properly filtered first to avoid aliasing that would otherwise occur). After that the frequency resolution is the inverse of the total time captured. You can window the data prior to taking the FFT which will allow to see both strong and weak signals (dynamic range) but know that this will degrade the resolution typically up to 2x depending on window used

Comment: So it's NOT increasing the samples specifically that helps resolution-- it is increasing the total time capture specifically. If the sampling rate is the same, then this is achieved by increasing the number of samples.

Answer (score 2):

According to the scipy.fft doc page, if you don't specify the FFT size it will use FFT size equal to the length of the input. At sampling rate of 256 Hz and input size of 100 samples, each frequency bin will be 2.56 Hz wide. If you want to have smaller frequency bins, increase the FFT size. For example, try FFT size of 512 or 1024 for frequency bins that are 0.5 Hz or 0.25 Hz wide respectively.

**Edit**

Thanks Dan B. for making sure I'm being specific in my answer. To clarify, I assume the sampling rate is fixed. Further, when I say "increase the FFT size", I mean give the FFT more samples of your signal - not running a 512- or 1024-point FFT on your original 100 samples which would be zero-padding your data. You can interpolate via zero-padding and still might not get what you're after. Interpolating isn't adding any new information, think about it, you're taking your data and appending zeros to the end of it and running FFT on that, how could doing that give you more real information? You need to give more real information by providing more samples of the signal.

One suggestion for your application, figure out what frequency resolution you want and create an array of zeros of that size. Every 100 samples that you get, push those samples through that array first-in first-out style. Until that array is eventually filled with samples of your signal, you will be running a zero-padded FFT on 100, 200, 300, ... samples and will just get an interpolated output, but once that array is filled you'll be getting your desired frequency resolution on the most recent data.